# What kind of errors are these

Tags: c++

```
1>temp q.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall         queue<int>::~queue<int>(void)" (??1?$queue@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>temp q.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall  queue<double>::~queue<double>(void)" (??1?$queue@N@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>temp q.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall queue<char>::~queue<char>(void)" (??1?$queue@D@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>temp q.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall queue<double>::pop(void)" (?pop@?$queue@N@@QAEHXZ) referenced in function _main
1>temp q.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall queue<char>::pop(void)" (?pop@?$queue@D@@QAEHXZ) referenced in function _main
1>temp q.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall queue<int>::pop(void)" (?pop@?$queue@H@@QAEHXZ) referenced in function _main
1>temp q.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall queue<double>::top(double &)" (?top@?$queue@N@@QAEHAAN@Z) referenced in function _main
1>temp q.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall queue<int>::top(int &)" (?top@?$queue@H@@QAEHAAH@Z) referenced in function _main
1>temp q.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall queue<char>::top(char &)" (?top@?$queue@D@@QAEHAAD@Z) referenced in function _main
1>temp q.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall queue<char>::push(char)" (?push@?$queue@D@@QAEHD@Z) referenced in function _main
1>temp q.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall queue<double>::push(double)" (?push@?$queue@N@@QAEHN@Z) referenced in function _main
1>temp q.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall queue<int>::push(int)" (?push@?$queue@H@@QAEHH@Z) referenced in function _main
1>temp q.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall queue<char>::queue<char>(void)" (??0?$queue@D@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>temp q.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall queue<double>::queue<double>(void)" (??0?$queue@N@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>temp q.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall queue<int>::queue<int>(void)" (??0?$queue@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>C:\Users\a 2\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\temp stack\Debug\temp stack.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 15 unresolved externals
```

Can someone please highlight what kind of errors are these?

Comment: You need to either compile the .cpp file which implements `queue` or link to a library which implements it.  BTW, I've removed the C tag since the errors show that you're using C++

Comment: Linker kind of this errors

Comment: Something says me you've put the implementation of `queue` methods in a cpp file!?

Comment: ok i put the implement in class and put the header (queue.h) .. i donot have any thing about this error and i'n sorry about tag (c) :)

Comment: i tried this ,, but the errors raised

Comment: What are the cpp/header files you created? and what did you include/implement in each of them? That helps us suggest you how to compile and link the pieces

Comment: queue.h-> that is class... #pragma once
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 
#define success 0
#define overflow -1
#define underflow -2
typedef int error;

template <class T>
struct Node{
 T data;
 Node <T> *next;
 
 
 };

template <class T>
 
class queue{
 
protected: 
Node <T> * front;
Node<T> * rear; 
int c;

public:
 
 queue();
 ~queue();
 error pop();
 error top(T &x);
 error push(T x);
 bool empty();
 bool full(){return false;}



};

Comment: @AnasShami: That header doesn't define the functions, it only declares them. Templates usually need to be defined in headers, as described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021).

Comment: i define it as a header (template)

Answer (score 0):

It is a linker error. There is code somewhere trying to call the functions for the queue class, but there is no queue class linked into the executable.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/compiler_linker_errors.html

Comment: what should i do ?! thank you for website but i need solve this